# Should I flag multiple posts from a spammer?

Tags: discussion

I've had a couple of experiences lately where I've noticed users posting (presumably) their own website/project links as answers on multiple questions. Here's an example: https://ux.stackexchange.com/users/87392/vladimir-georgiev

In cases like this, should I bother flagging each of the answers where they have promoted their site, or should I just flag one and rely on the respondent to find the others?

Edit: To be clear, the reason I ask is because the "spam" option doesn't offer any way to include your own remarks, so I'm concerned that it will look like I'm unfairly targetting a specific user, when in fact each post flagged for spam is a legitimate flag.

Answer (score 2):

In the cases I've seen the same links, however he does answer as examples of - not to encourage on to purchase anything. I may be wrong, but so far I found no evidence of encourage users to buy anything.

But thanks for letting us know - we'll keep a close eye on this case. Asking for 3rd party paid for solutions is off topic, but answering is a little trickier.

Comment: That was really just an example, but my question is more general. In cases where I believe a user is spamming, do I report just one post, or all that I find? Also re: my example, if you check his posts they're only barely (if at all) on topic and incredibly brief, just long enough to throw in a link to his product. For example: http://ux.stackexchange.com/a/98227/51454. The question is asking how to indicate to a user that zoom/pan is available. His answer doesn't address this at all, and in fact the link he provides is the opposite of what the OP wanted.

Comment: One is good enough, but make sure you explain well, and we can follow user activity from there...

Comment: That's the problem, when you flag something as spam, you don't get offered anywhere to provide an explanation.

Comment: Use another flag type where you can provide a comment. It makes things easier for us 

Comment: No problem at all, that sounds like a good solution. Thanks Benny!